# SD card being wiped by iMac

Tags: imac, video, sd-card, video-editing

I put the SD card with all the film footage on it, into the reader.

I create folders, and also put the footage on to the SSD and the cloud....typical post-shoot file maintenance.

I eject the SD card from the imac. SD card is now empty.

On my PC, this N E V E R happens!

I want the footage to remain physically on the SD card. Why is this happening???

Comment: Something else must be happening other than mere insertion/ejection of the SD card. I've literally used a succession of my own, and my employer's, iMacs over the years to extract photos and video files from many SD cards. You state that you 'create folders'. Where are these folders created? On the SD card?

Comment: I'm sure you know that you must eject the SD card from the iMac (drag the card to the Trash icon, for example) before you remove it from the slot.

Comment: You don't say what you use to do the copying. But photos.app and possibly others have an option for removing files from the source after copying Regardless it is important not to write ANYTHING to the card. As that could make make data recovery impossible.

Comment: It does sound more like (stating the obvious I know sorry) it was a "move" operation instead of a "copy" . Good point about app removing source, different thing but Winrar did that at one point to me until I found the option to stop it. How it got set that way idk.

Comment: thanks guys...i am a beginner so there are tons of things i probably did without realizing it. all footage accounted for in multiple clouds and SSDs so i lost nothing...not sure what happened..it may well have been a move operation instead of a copy one...not sure

Comment: Next time you want to transfer proceed like this: Select all the footage/folders from the SD. Hit ``cmd`` + ``c`` and go to the directory on your mac you want to copy the files to. In your preferred folder, hit ``cmd`` + ``v``. Without further ado, eject the SD card. Then organize your files on the mac and distribute it to clouds...